# ALTER ROLE to drop all members

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012, and my main goal is to programmatically `DROP ROLE`, but that cannot be done unless the role is empty, so how can I use T-SQL to first drop all members of a role?

- I can find all members of a role:

  ```
  SELECT members.[name] 
  FROM sys.database_role_members AS rolemembers
      JOIN sys.database_principals AS roles 
          ON roles.[principal_id] = rolemembers.[role_principal_id]
      JOIN sys.database_principals AS members 
          ON members.[principal_id] = rolemembers.[member_principal_id]
  WHERE roles.[name]=@rolename
  ```
- Members can be dropped using:

  ```
  ALTER ROLE role_name DROP MEMBER user_name
  ```

How can I combine these two? Or is there another way to do what I'm trying to do?

<sub><sup>(Also, I'm not sure if this is important, but I will be using this in an Entity Framework 6 migration)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how I would combine the two:

```
DECLARE @rolename sysname = 'role_name';
DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @cmd = @cmd + '
    ALTER ROLE ' + QUOTENAME(@rolename) + ' DROP MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(members.[name]) + ';'
FROM sys.database_role_members AS rolemembers
    JOIN sys.database_principals AS roles 
        ON roles.[principal_id] = rolemembers.[role_principal_id]
    JOIN sys.database_principals AS members 
        ON members.[principal_id] = rolemembers.[member_principal_id]
WHERE roles.[name]=@rolename

EXEC(@cmd);
```

This creates a string with your `ALTER ROLE` command for every row (user) in your query, concatenates them all together into one big string with all of those commands and then dynamically executes them.

Answer (score 2):

There is special [sp (`sp_droprolemember`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188369.aspx) in sql server. I hope, it solves you problem.

Comment: sp_droprolemember is deprecated - use ALTER ROLE instead (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188369.aspx)